# How to make an intersection between two meshes seem like they are one

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, extrude, intersection

I am trying to make a model of a small creature, whose limps and ears are connected to its main body.
I made the ears out of a different mesh instead of an extrusion, the problem is: it looks like it is a different mesh instead of an extension of the body:

[image]

What I did with the arm on the other hand is an extrusion which makes the connection between the arm and the body seem more natural:
[image]

How can I make the intersection between the ear and the body look more like the one between the arm and the body?

Comment: maybe just extrude forthe ears?

Comment: If it's high poly, you can join the ears with a boolean and then smooth the geometry out in sculpt mode. If it's low poly then the easiest would be to just connect them manually to look similar to the extrusion  you made